# Target a specific file size for a WebP image on Android

Tags: java, android, webp

I'm well aware that this is usually not a useful thing to think about, however I have encountered a (somewhat contrived) situation where I would like to target a specific file size for a WebP image. [Apparently, googles own cwebp tool for desktop has the ability to target a specific size](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp#lossy_options), but I after combing the Bitmap docs for any mention of the tuning of this parameter I found nothing. I haven't been able to search for other Java libraries either, because it seems that most people are content with the builtin encoding/decoding ability natively available in Android.

Comment: You should go for resolution instead of file size.

Comment: @blackapps This is a contrived situation being imposed on me - I can't change the requirements

Comment: But what is your problem. Make a loop with bitmap.compress() in a byte array output stream and look at amount of bytes in stream. Simple. No library needed. Code has been posted a lot of times too.